# Add Google Analytics Tracking Code to website created using Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: html, google-analytics, ms-word

How do I add the Google Analytics tracking code to a website created through Microsoft Word 2010? I'll be tweaking the site through Word, so I want a solution that works through Word (not editing the HTML output through another program).

I know you're going to tell me that Microsoft Word is a bad choice as an HTML editor, but my collaborator insisted on it, so please don't respond if you can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Get your code snipped (you have to create an account first),
register your site, add the code snipped to you code - you are ready to go.

But really...you could´ve pasted the code into word afterwards...and this is not directly a question for SO...you could have googled it...

https://www.google.de/analytics/